# Swift 5 SIMD distance

Tags: swift, simd

How would I use the new Swift 5 SIMD types to do what `simd_distance` does? Just to give a simple example, how would I calculate the hypotenuse of a right triangle from two SIMD2 values representing points? Or is the idea that I just go right on using `simd_distance`? (In which case, what's the advantage of making the SIMD types native in the first place?)

For example, suppose I used to say

```
let pt1 = simd_make_double2(...,...)
let pt2 = simd_make_double2(...,...)
let hypotenuse = simd_distance(pt1, pt2)
```

What would I say now?

Comment: I don't see why it's "too broad".

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but this question is definitely on-topic for SO. It’s the exact kinds of questions that should be here. My guess is they haven’t fleshed out SIMD support enough yet.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no generic version of `simd_distance` (or `simd_length`, ... ,  not even of the SIMD matrix types).

Comment: @MartinR Does that constitute grounds for a bug report? I was hoping there was some operator whose existence I was just missing somehow.

Comment: If you have to do this very much, you're using SIMD wrong.  Horizontal adds *within* a SIMD vector are not efficient.  And you don't get to take advantage of `sqrtpd` / `sqrtps` to calculate 2 or 4 packed SQRT values in parallel.  What SIMD can do efficiently is calculate 2 or 4 vector lengths in parallel from an array of `horizontal[]` and an array of `vertical[]` distances.  See these slides for an intro to using SIMD efficiently. https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/  It uses x86 and C++ but the AoS vs. SoA concept applies to AArch64 as well.

Comment: But if you're programming a GPU, not a CPU, this is fine.  GPUs aren't stuck with CPU-style short-vector SIMD and can easily do horizontal stuff to adjacent elements.

Comment: "If you have to do this very much, you're using SIMD wrong" @PeterCordes I'm not "using" it at all. I'm just trying to explore it. It is claimed that Swift now has native SIMD types that replace the library `simd...` calls. I'm looking to see whether that's true.

Comment: I don't know Swift, I'm here for the `[simd]` tag.  I'm just trying to warn you that using SIMD *this way* is a potentially-inefficient road to go down, and you might get the wrong idea about whether SIMD is even useful for your program.  Don't let me stop you from finding out what the language supports, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Cool and that's useful to know but the topic sentence of the question is "the new Swift 5 SIMD types" and the title contains "Swift 5 SIMD".

Comment: That's why I *commented* instead of answering :P  Not all comments have to attempt to answer the question, and in fact should *not*.

Comment: @PeterCordes And it's a useful comment, as I said.

Comment: *“Does that constitute grounds for a bug report?”* – I do not have sufficient knowledge about this topic to judge that. You could also ask on the Swift Forum first.  Stephen Canon (the author of the SIMD additions, and apparently an expert on that topic) is active on those lists.

Comment: @matt: (Sorry for badgering you here, feel free to ignore!) – With respect to your recent (already deleted)  question: Another option might be to make struct generic over the wrapped type, not over the optional type. Something like `struct S<W> { typealias T = Optional<W>; func f(_:W) {} }`

Comment: @MartinR I didn’t describe the real problem. I’m trying to write a Swift 5.1 property wrapper that will apply to outlet properties without the optional backing store ending up as a double wrapped optional (outlets must be optional). So I need to be able to say, “In case this is an Optional, unwrap it.”